# GNOME animations laggy in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: intel-graphics, ubuntu-gnome

I'm currently running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on a laptop with 8GB of RAM and an Integrated Intel HD Graphics 405 Graphics Card. Right from the first day, I've noticed that animations have been very very laggy.

But when I installed Ubuntu GNOME on my friends' laptops with an Nvidia graphics card, everything worked smoothly. One day, I tried out Ubuntu with Unity on a live USB, and noticed that everything worked smoothly. So I came to the conclusion that it was a problem with GNOME.

But then today, I tried out Fedora 26 on a live USB, and noticed that all the animations worked perfectly. Everything on the whole worked much smoother. So now, I'm convinced that it's not a problem with GNOME itself.

What should I do now? 17.10 is coming out soon. Should I wait to see if that will fix it? Is this a problem only with my version of Ubuntu GNOME? What could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 - Graphics problems on kernel 4.10.0-37-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963718/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-graphics-problems-on-kernel-4-10-0-37-generic)

Comment: How long have you been facing this "lagginess"? I'm having no issue with the animations in a laptop weaker than yours. I'll suggest you to try 17.10 beta in a live USB and see if there's any improvement. Also you can try the [Impatience extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/) to speed up animation as a workaround.

Comment: @pomsky I've been facing this problem right from the first time I installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. (I actually reinstalled twice due to other problems that were my fault). I'll try out what you suggested, though. Thank you :)

Comment: Often if the CPU is used for the graphics rendering instead of the GPU, you will experience sluggish graphics.  Please install mesa-utils `sudo apt install mesa-utils` and then execute the command `glxinfo | grep renderer`, and append the output of this last command to your question.

Comment: You are not the only one. I do experience them too. I had to switch to KDE plasma and it is fine. impatience extension is not helping with the jitters.

Comment: @Mohamad Well, in the question, I've mentioned that it ran fine on a Fedora 26 live USB. But once installed (and after installing some other applications), GNOME started lagging again terribly. Right now, I'm on Arch, with KDE Plasma 5.13, and everything is working perfectly. Not a bit of lag or choppiness or anything. Very low RAM usage too.